# call keyboard through java script on UIButton click

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, jquery-ui

I need to open key board on button click and at same time to show cursor which it was on earlier location on UIWebview. I am totally unknown to java script. Here is my code

```
  - (IBAction)keyboardButtonSelected:(id)sender {    
NSString *jScriptString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getCurrentCursor"];
[webViewForEditing stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jScriptString];

[keyboardButton setSelected:YES];
[keyboardButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyboard-light"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[viewForHomeEmoji removeFromSuperview];
```

}

and i wrote method in in script as:

```
   function getCurrentCursor
    {
        document.getElementById('content').focus();
    }

    <body>
    <div id="content" contenteditable="true" style="font-family: Helvetica">This is out Rich Text Editing View </div>
</body>
```

Guide me what i need to write to achieve this objective. Any tutorial that can made me familiar with java script combination with objective-C.
 Guide me